# Is there anyway to store dynamic PHP value in JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JavaScript function for scrolling of table when button is click but I have multiple tables in my code and cant use multiple function for each table I want to store the id's of all table in dynamic way using PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Do something in JavaScript
    var x = <?php echo $row_[document_id]; ?>;
    // etc..
</script>
```

document_id is were value are accessed dynamically in PHP.

Comment: PHP is executed server-side and then the page is rendered client-side

Comment: take a look at `ajax()`. Once you get the hang of it I believe your question should be answered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
var x = <?php echo $row_[document_id]; ?>;
```

you can use something like this:

```
<?php

echo '<script>var x = ' . $row_document_id . ';</script>';

?>
```

If data is a string, you can use double quotes:

```
<?php
echo '<script>var x = "' . $row_document_id . '";</script>';
?>
```

Also it is preferred to use `let` instead of `var`.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Save the PHP variable value in HTML hidden input element.

```
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_[document_id]?>" id="getValue">
```

And then get the value from JavaScript or jQuery.

```
    var x = $("#getValue").val();
```